# How does Transaction Controller have a separate average time in Summary report and the overall report has a separate average time

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I ran a Jmeter script with all the samples under a transaction controller as shown in below image

[image]

Then when I got the summary report for this test and found in the report under average column that the transaction controller shows the total of all average time of samples. 
Question 1: Why does transaction controller show as a sample as well?
Question 2: (Check below summary report image) Isn't the total average supposed to be 7608/17 (where transaction controller average is 7608 and number of samples is 17) if you see the summary report below you can see the average time shown is double the value. 7608/17*2 = 895. Can you please explain the reason for doubling it.
Similarly when I ran the test for 20 users the average was 895 which I think arrived in the form 7608/340*40= 895 (Transaction controller average time= 7608, Number of samples = 340) There too I don't understand why the value 40 (which is double the number of users) is multiplied. Please Explain Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. This is the whole idea of the Transaction Controller - to measure cumulative duration of all the samplers in its scope so measure the time it takes for them **all** to complete
2. This is not the average, this is the **sum**.

See [Using JMeter's Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) article for comprehensive information on using the Transaction Controller.

Comment: Ok so can you explain me why we divide the sum showed in transaction controller by the number of samples and multiply by double the number of users?

Comment: `TOTAL` == average. `Transaction Controller` == sum. In case of using Transaction Controller TOTAL seems to be counting `Transaction Controller` as well (which sounds like a JMeter bug to me).